# Manipulating unicode characters in Scala

Tags: scala, unicode

I am trying to creating some unicode characters from numbers:

```
  (4 to 8).map(asUnicode("\\u207" + _)).foreach(println("P" + _))
```

This should print P^4 to P^8, but I don't know how the `asUnicode` function should be implemented.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind. I found out that this works:

```
  ('\u2074' to '\u2078').foreach(println _)
```